# Adding multiple Notion relations in Integromat (Notion API)

Tags: notion-api, make.com

Attempting to add multiple Notion relations in integromat:

- Desired result: Both students are added to the database
- Observed result: Each student is replaced with the iteration, so only the last
  the student is added to the database (not both)

Any guidance on how to manage this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem while updating a "Relations" field in a Notion database with multiple Relations.  The Iterator module is not needed.

Instead, in the "Update a Database Item" module, you can use the map() function in the destination field to process the "array of Collections" represented by the multiple student records as follows:

```
map(2.properties_value.students[]; id; id)
```

Additionally, if you would like to "append" another record to that result from another module, you can use the add() function as follows:

```
add(map(2.properties_value.student[]; id; id); 3.otherstudentid; 6.yetanotherstudentid)
```

It seems that Notion doesn't mind having duplicates in the relation field, as it ignores any extras it might receive.